# Using WCF REST HTML5 form

Tags: wcf, html

I want to use WCF REST service methods in my HTML5 form. I guess I can use JQuery for this. Can some one please provide some links of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this blog post](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/03/rest.html) about Create REST service with WCF and Consume using jQuery